# Allow contravariant use of `Array.includes` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, covariance

Consider this code:

```
interface Item {
   value?: string
}

const excludeValues = (
  items: Item[],
  excludedValues: string[]
): Item[] => items.filter(item => !excludedValues.includes(item.value))
```

This yields a type error that "Type `undefined` is not assignable to `string`" because `item.value` could be `undefined`, therefore `excludedValues.includes(item.value)` is not permitted.

However, the code would work 100% correctly in all cases, because `includes` is by nature contravariant and despite the fact that `values` is `string[]`, there is no harm in comparing `undefined` to them all (and not matching any).

What is a good way to get around this?

- It would be nice, but quite heavy and probably not acceptable in code review to declare an override on the `lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts` lib file to indicate the `includes` signature is contravariant ([TypeScript 4.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#optional-variance-annotations-for-type-parameters)?).
- Use a non-nullable assertion `.includes(item.value!)`? Eslint rules don't like that one.
- Use `as string`? That looks very suspicious because `as` so often hides bugs and ways things are being done wrong.
- Define the `excludedValues` parameter as `(string | undefined)[]`? This seems like vandalizing the method just to keep TypeScript happy.

It's not proving easy to decide on a good way to handle this.

Comment: Note that this isn't really about covariance or contravariance, logically it is safe to call `.includes` with any argument of any type, at worst the result is only going to be `false`, so the issue is only that TS's standard library has a too-restrictive type definition for `includes`. The override fix would not be to declare the parameter as contravariant (this only applies to *type* parameters, not function parameters, anyway) - it would be to declare the method as accepting `unknown`. However, this means you would potentially miss some mistakes that the type-checker could otherwise catch.

Comment: @kaya3 Gosh, I guess it probably does, so I'll vote to close my own question as a duplicate... doing that instead of deleting to preserve the possible search term funneling.